# How to create an Excel macro to consolidate AND sort data based on a unique identifier

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, macros

Full disclosure: I'm a total VB novice. But I'm learning and could really use some help creating a macro in excel. I've been working on this for 2 days now and can't seem to figure out the right approach. Basically, I need to move the data from multiple rows with vertical data to one row with multiple columns sorted horizontally. Here is the breakdown:

1. Condense multiple rows of data with a matching "GroupNumber" - deleting the extra rows once the data is consolidated with the first row.
2. Consolidate all the vertical data from each cell in Column C (T-CarrierHealth_1.Carrier) with the same "GroupNumber" into the 1st row with the "GroupNumber".
3. Sort the data into new columns based on the carrier name from column C (T-CarrierHealth_1.Carrier).

For example:
Here is the spreadsheet that I begin with:

[image: Before Spreadsheet]

And here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: After Spreadsheet]

Can anyone help me figure out the best method for this? I may need to manipulate the macro each month so I really want to understand the method behind it all. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is actually a pivot table rather than a macro so that you don't have to bother with changing the data.

It won't look quite like your output example as the cells will contain a 1 (one) rather than the word but you would immediately be able to see which companies have which features.